# Void in carbon frame seat tube, is it dangerous?

Tags: frames, safety, carbon

While assembling a carbon bike, I found this void in its seat tube. It's about 1/2 inch X 1/4 inch in size and I'm guessing almost a third to half the depth of the tube wall.

Since it's right next to the clamp, it looks like a catastrophic failure waiting to happen. What would be your opinion about this? Would this bike be safe to ride? Is there anything that can be done to repair it?

[image: Carbon seat tube void]

Comment: Can you confirm that the material all around that area is non-metallic? It looks kind of like the entire seat cluster is a cast aluminum piece.

Comment: Looks definitely metallic, especially if you look at the edge at the top where the paint has flaked off.

Comment: I checked with a magnet, it's non metallic. My guess is the grey stuff is a resin or epoxy. It looks similar to the inside of the fork tube. You can also see the carbon weave in the layer at the bottom of the void.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Of course, aluminum is not magnetic. But I don't think the area at the top of the seat tube is aluminum. Picture shows a metal insert to provide threads for tightening screws. If the surrounding material was metal, it would have been easier to beef up the rear of the tube and use that to form the threads.

Comment: The edge of the hole is red like the paint of the frame. So it is certainly there from the beginning and should have been noticed by quality control and the frame be rejected. Or, there was no real quality control and I would have serious doubts about the frame anyway. Other possibility, it was noticed by quality control and considered no problem. Next possibility, it was noted and dismissed because hidden, then it's outright criminal.

Comment: @carel, yeah that's what really bothers me too. You are right, the bottom of the hole has paint on it, so they knew it was there and ignored it. I would never feel safe riding this bike even if it doesn't fall apart during assembly. This frame is going back.

Comment: If it was new, check with the supplier about warranty and being "unfit for purpose"

Comment: @criggie, that's what I've done. Thanks for confirming my suspicion.

Comment: @DhirajBokde so, what happened in the end?  Do feel free to post your own answer, that's totally okay by stackexchange.

Comment: Marking question as Closed because OP found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're that worried about the void, i would suggest taking it to a carbon frame repair specialists and ask them their advice.

Answer (score -2):

it is ok if it is in seattube,the void it is not a complete circle,the surrounding material will provide enough support and the seat tube will bear most impact during riding,it fine and safe to riding except for extremely aggressive riding.